# Drop down menu list with image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i make an image preview for drop down item like the below link. 
https://www.jumeirah.com/en/hotels-resorts/dubai/burj-al-arab/?currency=AED&gclid=Cj0KEQiA25rFBRC8rfyX1vjeg7YBEiQAFIb3b_5nlK1PNwQxRSn6cEP2Y1mEwqHjzC4w5ruyEXBTTOIaAsVZ8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=COPghJmzl9ICFa8i0wodPXkEew

If you mouse over on the "Hotels and Resorts" in the menu, a drop down will appear. Then if you mouse over any item on drop down we can see a preview image. How can i make something like that ? Drop down i can make, But the issue is with the preview images. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you get the image?

Answer (score 0):

that's a jquery function ... all you have to do is something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_item").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#pic_box").css("background-image", "url(image.jpg)");
    });
    $("#menu_item").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#pic_box").css("background-image", "url(other-image.jpg)");
    });
});
```

and repeat that for each menu item